# PHP Curl при котором получатель не увидит реальный IP. При этом получать ответ скрипту нет необходимости. Нужно просто отправить статистику

Tags: php

PHP Curl при котором получатель не увидит реальный IP. При этом получать ответ скрипту нет необходимости. Нужно отправить статистику.

Comment: А вопрос тут есть?

Comment: через прокси только